# Hibernate persists duplicates for ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, duplicates, many-to-many

In my testing spring class I'm trying to populate my db in a @BeforeAll method.

```
@BeforeAll
static void beforeAll(@Autowired TeamRepository teamRepository,
                      @Autowired StudentRepository studentRepository) {

    teams = new ArrayList<>();
    students = new ArrayList<>();

    final int nTeams = 20;

    IntStream.range(0, nTeams)
            .forEach(i -> {

                Team team = Team.builder()
                        .name("team-"+i)
                        .status(TeamStatus.ACTIVE)
                        .members(new ArrayList<>())
                        .build();
                teams.add(team);

                teamRepository.save(team);

                IntStream.range(0, 3)
                        .forEach(k -> {

                            Student student = Student.builder()
                                    .id("s" + k + "-" + i)
                                    .name("name-" + k + "-" + i)
                                    .firstName("first_name-" + k + "-" + i)
                                    .teams(new ArrayList<>())
                                    .build();
                            team.addStudent(student);
                            students.add(student);

                            studentRepository.save(student);
                        });

            });

}
```

The relationship between the two entites is @ManyToMany.

`Student.java`

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Student {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    String id;
    String name;
    String firstName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTeam(Team team) {
        teams.add(team);
        team.members.add(this);
    }

    public void removeTeam(Team team) {
        teams.remove(team);
        team.members.remove(this);
    }
}
```

`Team.java`

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    Long id;
    String name;
    TeamStatus status;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "team_student",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    List<Student> members = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        members.add(student);
        student.teams.add(this);
    }

    public void removeStudent(Student student) {
        members.remove(student);
        student.teams.remove(this);
    }
}
```

With this code Hibernate will persist duplicates as shown in the images below. The only solution I found is to do not invoke `studentRepository.save()` and to save the `team` only at the end.
The reason I'm posting this question is that I'm trying to understand why this happens and why the duplicates number is different for different entities.

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So this happening in integration test? Is the image a debug screenshot?

Comment: This is a db setup happening before all unit tests. The screenshots are the entities being saved into the the db.